# Are dynamic imports destroyed after function finished?

Tags: javascript, import, dynamic-import

Please correct me if I'm wrong. On the first function, `module1` gets imported, and when the function finishes, the constant that's carrying the module is destroyed, and the module is no more. Does the same thing happen for the second function as well? I mean, does the module get imported once again in the second function? If it does, is there any way to cache the import so that the second function doesn't have to waste time importing it once again after the first function finishes execution?

```
const someFunc = async data => {
   try {
      const x = await import(`module1`);
   } catch err {
      console.log(err);
   }
}

const anotherFunc = async data => {
   try {
      const x = await import(`module1`);
   } catch err {
      console.log(err);
   }
}
```

Comment: you can test it yourself ... put a console.log in `module1` - does it get output again?

Comment: or, if you can't be bothered, then, no, it is not "imported again"